# Taking multiple prices on single page BS4

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm creating an to help me learn but is also useful to me. I want to be able to parse multiple prices from (https://www.watchfinder.co.uk/search?q=114060&orderby=AgeNewToOld) one page, convert them to numbers and average them. The page will change so it could have 3 prices one day and 20 the next. The part i am struggling with is separating the prices so that i can use them.
So far i have:

```
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


price = soup.find_all(class_=('prods_price'))
for price in price:
    price = price.text
    price = " ".join(price.split())
    price = price.split('£')
    price = [y.replace(',', '') for y in price]
    price = list(map(int, price[1:]))
    print(price)
```

Which gives me

```
[9450]
[8750]
[8450]
```

Baring in mind that the amount of prices can change, how can I separate these? Or is there a way with BS4 that can get all these without forlooping?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: I want to be able to take these and average them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will provide the average value for all prices,

```
URL = 'https://www.watchfinder.co.uk/search?q=114060&orderby=AgeNewToOld'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

prices = soup.find_all(class_=('prods_price'))
price_list  = [int((price.text).replace('£', '').replace(',', '')) for price in prices]
print(price_list)

def Average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

print(Average(price_list))
```

**output:**

> [9250, 8750, 8450]
>
> 8816.666666666666

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes